# overlap tabbarview with tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

I need to implement tab like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12iVI.png

I have done tabBar Using this Code I am not getting transparent background as like in the attached picture

```
     Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: TabBar(
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Color(0xffD65A32)),
                insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0)),
            isScrollable: true,
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text("Maps", style: tabStyle),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Sections", style: tabStyle),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Events", style: tabStyle),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Gallery", style: tabStyle),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Archives", style: tabStyle),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              MyHomePage(),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Here its my code for tab

Comment: what is the issue with your requirement? background is not getting transparent?

Comment: Then replace your Column widget with Stack for overlapping on other widgets. because Stack widget behaves like relative layout.

Comment: Yeah..I need implement like as  the attached image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you actually want is the behavior of a `Stack`, not the behavior of a `Column` since you want to `TabBar` to be in front of your content and not above.

Means simply changing the `Column` to a `Stack` and pushing the `TabBar` at the end of the `children` Array for bringing it to the front should be the trick.

Here is the code I suggest:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TabController controller = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 5,
      vsync: this
    );

    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        TabBarView(
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.red),
            Container(color: Colors.blue),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow),
            Container(color: Colors.green),
            Container(color: Colors.purple),
          ],
        ),
        Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: TabBar(
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Color(0xffD65A32)),
                insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0)),
            isScrollable: true,
            controller: controller,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text("Maps",),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Sections",),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Events",),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Gallery",),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text("Archives",),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```